# FFMPEG: add more tracks to previous amix output

Tags: shell, audio, filter, ffmpeg, audio-recording

I can mix multiple audio tracks in ffmpeg with a command like

```
ffmpeg -i track1.wav \
       -i track2.wav \
       -i track3.wav \
       -filter_complex "[0:a] [1:a] [2:a] amix=3 [out]" \
       -map "[out]" \
       -c copy mix.wav
```

All tracks are the same length in my use-case. Periodically, I'll receive a new track (call it `track4.wav`) and I would like to produce a new mix of all four tracks. The naive solution would be to re-run the above comment with with the additional track, but this becomes expensive as the number of tracks gets large.

Is there an elegant way to combine `mix.wav` and `track4.wav` to get the equivalent result, without an imbalance in volume levels or significant loss of quality compared to the "naive" approach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As long as you are saving to PCM/WAV, there's no quality loss to speak of.

With a recent version of ffmpeg, you can run

```
ffmpeg -i mixof3.wav \
       -i track4.wav \
       -filter_complex "[0:a] [1:a] amix=2:weights='3 1' [out]" \
       -map "[out]" \
       mixof4.wav
```

This is equivalent to having run your original command with 4 inputs.

Comment: After a lot of testing, I can confirm this works a treat!